# How to delete a page and copy and paste a page using powershell

Tags: powershell, office

I am trying to delete a page from office 365 SharePoint using PowerShell and Copy and Paste a page and rename it.

```
We have two pages 
1: home.aspx
2: home_old.aspx

1: We want to delete the page home_old.aspx.
2: We want to make a copy of the page Home.aspx. and make new page called home_old.aspx so it will copy all the webparts from Home page to home_old page.
```

We have many page likes that so we are planning to do it using **PowerShell**.

Comment: Can you not use SharePoint Designer?
Also look into this link : http://sharepointmaven.com/copy-pages-sharepoint-online/

Comment: create folder in pages library and copy pages from rootfolder to subfolder , after coping the pages delete from rootfolder using powershell

Comment: We have so many pages in our site so we can't do it one by one. thats why we want Power Shell command.